# NVMe PCIe SSD using 2 lanes instead of 4

Tags: ssd, pci-express, nvme, benchmarking, crystaldiskinfo

I recently installed an WD Blue SN570 500GB NVMe SSD in my HP laptop and I did a benchmark test in crystal disk software and got 1700MBps read speed but this SSD supports 3500MBps.

When I checked in crystal disk info software I see laptop is using only 2 lanes instead of 4 please see the attached picture. I've HP pavilion 15-cc152od model with i5-8260U 8gb ram. and it supports the PCIe 3.0x4. But I don't understand what went wrong and it shows current mode as PCIe 3.0x2 connected and I'm getting exactly half the speed of the SSD that was given.

[image]

Comment: How do you know it supports x4? The laptop, I mean. Given its age and the NVMe slot being sort of an afterthought (originally sold with just a 5400rpm SATA HDD) it may not support more than what you got. If you have specifications telling you otherwise, from HP, then please post then by [edit]ing the question.

Comment: There is no specific x4 lanes mentioned in HP they just mentioned nvme PCIe SSD upto 512 gb. But in the crystal disk info it shows x4 in supported mode

Comment: Try fiddling with the BIOS. Perhaps it is shared and something else is grabbing those lanes

Comment: The [HP service guide](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c06525445.pdf) for your model suggests that the NVMe slot supports both NVMe and SATA. It may be that as a result only 2 of the 4 PCIe lanes are wired up. HP documentation on that slot is incredibly sparce, you may need to contact them directly. That x4 is supported is likely what the drive supports, it does not indicate what is actually wired up at the connector.

Comment: Oh..i see.. the transfer mode actually shows what SSD supports. I tried checking the bios HP has hidden the advanced setting in there so that bios menu is useless for me without it and there is nothing regarding ssds or storage. I think i would've saved few bucks by buying a 1000MBps SSD